# Trying to keep header links visible on all pages

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have added a My account link and a wishlist link to my header. It shows fine on the home page but when I go on to any other page, the images are no longer displayed, all I see is the Alt text.

Can someone help me tweak my code so that the same images are shown properly on all pages? :-)

I have tried to do it so that the pictures change color on hover by having one image below the other...

PHP:

```
<div id="myaccount">
    <a href="wordpress/my-account"><img class="bottom" src="wp-
content/themes/mt_theme/images/my_account_hover.png" alt="My 
Account"/> 
<img class="top" src="wp-content/themes/my_theme/images/my_account.png" alt="My Account"/>
        <p class="icotext">My Account</p>
    </a>
</div>
<div id="wishlist">
    <a href="wishlist"><img class="bottom2" src="wp-content/themes/smy_theme/images/wishlist_hover.ico" alt="Wishlist"/>
```

Wishlist

CSS:

```
#myaccount{
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#myaccount img {
  position:absolute;
  left:900px;
  top: -20px;
  Height: 50px !important;
  width: 50px !important;
} 
a:hover img.top {
  opacity:0;
}
.icotext{
  position: absolute;
  left: 890px;
  top: 28px;
  color: #000000  
}
a:hover .icotext{
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 888px;
}
#wishlist{
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#wishlist img {
  position:absolute;
  left:990px;
  top: -20px;
  Height: 50px !important;
  width: 50px !important;
}
.icotext2{
  position: absolute;
  left: 992px;
  top: 28px;
  color: #000000  
}
a:hover .icotext2{
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 990px;
}
a:hover img.top2 {
  opacity:0;
}
img.bottom2 {
  opacity:0;  
}
a:hover img.bottom2 {
  opacity:1;
}
img.bottom {
  opacity:0;
}
a:hover img.bottom {
   opacity:1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the other pages are trying to get the images from another folder.

```
src="wp-content/themes/my_theme/images/my_account.png"
```

You are using a relative address that is interpreted as "{current folder}/wp-content/..."
Try using

```
src="/wp-content/themes/my_theme/images/my_account.png"
```

The / on the front will be interpreted as "{site_root}/wp-content/..."

Comment: thanks for your answer.

I tried that but it has the opposite effect and now I cannot see the images on any page :-( lol

Comment: The leading / on the path points to the server's root, I don't know your server and page structure to help you further.

You can use still try to use absolute paths, ex:
     http : // www.yoursite.com/more-paths/your-image.png

Comment: Hi Marco, Thank you for your help. I realised my problem. I was linking it to a folder in localhost. I have uploaded the image to my wordpress media and it seems to work fine now.

thank you again